# Mongodb Sharding and Indexing

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

I have been struggling to deploy a large database.
I have deployed 3 shard clusters and started indexing my data.
However it's been 16 days and I'm only half way through.

Question is, should I import all data to a non sharded cluster and then activate sharding once the raw data is in the database and then attach more clusters and start indexing? Will this auto balance my data?

Or I should wait another 16 days for the current method I am using...

*Edit:
Here is more explanation of the setup and data that is being imported...

So we have 160 million documents that are like this

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5146ae7de4b0d58a864bcfda"),
"subject" : "<concept/resource/propert/122322xyz>",
"predicate" : "<concept/property/os/123ABCDXZYZ>",
"object" : "<http://host/uri_to_object_abcdy>"
```

Indexes: subject, predicate, object, subject > predicate, object > predicate 
Shard keys: subject, predicate, object

Setup:
3 clusters on AWS (each with 3 Replica sets) with each node having 8 GiB RAM
(Config servers are within each cluster and Mongos is in a separate server)

The data gets imported by a Java program into a the Mongos.
What would be the ideal way to import this data, index and shard. (without waiting a month for the process to be completed)

Comment: What shard key are you using? How many records are you importing, and their size? What kind of throughput are you getting? Generally, you should import to a sharded cluster and don't "shard later"... While it is possible, it's a pain

Comment: There are about 160 million documents each with at least 5 indexes and 5 shard keys...

Comment: Normally, it takes 2 hours to import that same data and almost half a day to index afterwards. (in a single mongod)

Comment: What do you mean by "5 indexes and 5 shard keys".  Is that a single compound index with 5 fields or 5 separate indexes.  I ask because you can only have 1 shard index... Also, the sharded setup should not take longer to populate and index. Can you describe the setup a little more,  where is the mongos in relation to the import application and shards.  Are the shards replica sets? single mongods? If a replica set how many members? What does the hardware configuration look like?

Comment: As a experiment (without stopping the running index operation) you could try importing the data into a different db/collection on the same cluster but with the indexes and sharding setup before you start the import. If the import normally takes a couple of hours you should know fairly quick if the pre-indexed setup will get to the end state faster.

Comment: Hi Rob, I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: Can you run db.COLL.getIndexes() (where COLL is you collection name) and post the output? I would like to confirm that you don't have redundant indexes. For example, if you have { subject: 1, predicate: 1} defined then you don't need a separate { subject: 1} index.

Comment: +1 to @JamesWahlin's request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a massive bulk insert, it is often faster to perform the insert without an index and then index the collection. This has to do with the way Mongo manages index updates on the fly.

Also, MongoDB is particularly sensitive to memory when it indexes. Check the size of your indexes in your [`db.stats()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-statistics/) and hook up your DBs to the [Mongo Monitoring Service](http://www.10gen.com/products/mongodb-monitoring-service).

In my experience, whenever MongoDB takes a lot more time than expected, it is due to one of two things:

1. It running out of physical memory or getting itself into a poor I/O pattern. MMS can help diagnose both. Check out the page faults graph in particular.
2. Operating on unindexed collections, which does not apply in your case.

Comment: Thanks sim. I am now analyzing with MMS

Comment: Did your analysis reveal anything interesting?